# google analytics for single page application only hide show divs

Tags: jquery, html, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, single-page-application

I have single page html webpage where there is hide and show of 5 divs showing only one at time .there is no anchor tag url remains same through out the application how can I use google analytics to track my website (different views and divs) which div is shown at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger virtual page views in your code when you hide/show div's in your code.

A virtual page view can be trigger using following code snippet:

`ga('send', 'pageview', '/page-name/');`

In the above snippet you replace `/page-name/` with the name of the div that you show.

That's all that's needed to do some basic tracking on a one page app.
For more information about the google analytics API [see the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages).

Comment: u mean when a button is pressed to hide current div and  show another div then run this code snippet ?